# Aligning elements inside absolutely positioned div

Tags: html, css

I want to build a vertical menu on the left side of my screen in html and css. With help of javascript it will pop in and out when clicked. Every entry in the menu should have an icon that I try to put in the background of a div, for centering then horizontally as an imaginary vertical axis will pass in the center of every icon.

The problem is, if I try to use inline-blocks they behave strangely and following div remains aligned with bottom of the previous one. Does anyone know how to solve this?

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <style type="text/css">
         .menu {
             width: 300px;
             height: 100%;
             position: absolute;
             left: 0px;
             top: 0px;
             z-index: 10;
             background: #abcdef;
         }

         .icon-block {

            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            display: inline-block;
            background-color: #fedcba;
            background-image: url('ico_menu.png');
            background-repeat: no-repeat;

         }

         .text-block {

            width: 230px;
            height: 50px;
            display: inline-block;
            background: #acbafe;
         }

         .a-block {
            display: block;
         }

      </style>
   </head>


   <body>
      <div class="menu">
         <a href="#" class="">
            <div class="icon-block"><!-- VOID BLOCK, BACKGROUND IMAGE --></div><div class="text-block">
                <span>Home</span>
            </div>
         </a>
         <div class="icon-block"><!-- VOID BLOCK, BACKGROUND IMAGE --></div><div class="text-block">
            <a href="#" class="a-block">
                About
            </a>
         </div>

      </div>
   </body>

</html>
```

Comment: show an image sketch of what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `float:right` to this class:

```
.text-block {
    float: right;/*Add this*/
    width: 230px;
    height: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #acbafe;
}
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8j36C/)

Comment: That's interesting. I thought that inline-block is enough and float it's little messy but it works! Great!

Answer (score 0):

As a understood your requirement, I created [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/3Z4k9/) with some changes to html structure and commented `display: inline-block;`.

Please check if it solves your problem, or if you can get a image/picture view that would be great.